# MariaDB - Foreign Key problem when reference SMALLINT

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, mariadb

I have a problem with MariaDB's foreign keys...
These are the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` binary(20) NOT NULL,
  `role` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 2,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_UN` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `roles_name_UN` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

---

I can't understand why when I try to update "users" with this command:

```sql
ALTER TABLE unito_tweb.users ADD CONSTRAINT users_role_FK FOREIGN KEY (`role`) REFERENCES unito_tweb.roles(id) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I get this error:

```
Can't create table `unito_tweb`.`users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Comment: Your code works fine without the qualified table name:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5bde79ad8c18418b3a5890f0f092a7c5.

Comment: I'm using "MariaDB 10.4.13" on Arch and it doesn't work in that case either...

Comment: I have `Server version: 10.1.21-MariaDB` ... and it fails for me too. Doesn't like the `SET` within the alter. If I change the `SET DEFAULT` to `NO ACTION`, then it works, but likely not what is desired.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, @Giuseppe ... Found [more info](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/#limitations) `The SET DEFAULT action is not supported.` for MariaDB. (darnit!)

Comment: Thanks @Paul-T , I saw...  
Anyway I think the support has been added by MariaDB 10.5, because in the site that gave GordonLinoff if you set that, the query works without problems...

Comment: @Giuseppe ... Ah, I see, thanks for pointing that out. I did not try that version. You had mentioned 10.4, and my 10.1, I assumed no support without actually checking that last version.